# Buildfire: How to use Webhooks

Tags: buildfire

I am wondering how I would be able to use Webhooks and allow Apple to verify the domain of an app or a plugin.

Thanks!
Alex Case

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by having Apple verify the domain of an app or a plugin?

Comment: To use Apple Pay, you need to register with Apple all of your web domains that will show an Apple Pay button. This includes both top-level domains (e.g., stripe.com) and subdomains (e.g., shop.stripe.com). You need to do this for domains you use in both production and testing.

I am wondering how I would register the domain for a plugin or app, since it is Buildfire's domain

Comment: Are you utilizing BuildFire's "In App Purchases" feature or are you trying to build something custom?

Comment: I am building something custom.